# How can I dynamically get parameters in the URL?

Tags: c#, mysql, url, razor, query-string

My problem is, that i want to build my webpage dynamically. I get all the Inforamtions from my database but I can't pass for an example the ID to an other page to build the new Page.
What i have so far:

```
MySqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
<a id="@r["ID"]" href="test.cshtml?id="+@r["ID"]  title="test" method="get" 
name="id">test</a>
```

The URL should look like:
~/test.cshtml?id=1

When I want to request the parameter with:

```
int message = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

I don't receive anything from my previous page.
The problem is that the URL is still `~/test.cshtml`.

Comment: Did you try with viewbag or viewdata?

Comment: No. Can u give me an example?

Comment: I assume you are on ASP.Net Core MVC. Here is example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1). It is almost the same as with classic ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
string QueryString = "test.cshtml?id=" + r["ID"].ToString(); 
<a id="@r["ID"]" href=@QueryString title="Detail" method="get" name="id">Details</a>
```

The problem was I tried to concatenate 2 string in an a tag, but that is not possible. So i tried to concatenate these 2 before and it works